# Adding locations to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, xy

I have coordinates of places that I would like to add to ArcMap. The coordinates are not written in long-lat format, so I am finding it difficult to use the "add xy" data command. For example, one coordinate is 7°35′13″N 1°56′06″W .

How can I add such coordinates to my shapefile?

Comment: Could you add a sample of the coordinate table to your question, for example 20 rows of it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not easy to map those decimal, degrees, minutes (DDM) coordinates to points. This [official support article](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010623) explains the process. However, if you have too many points, I suggest a bit of automation. [This SE post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997361/how-to-convert-degree-minute-second-to-degree-decimal) talks about how you can convert DDM to decimal degrees by using python.Basically, you can calculate your DDM as decimal degrees in two fields (X-Y or Long-Lat). Then you can use "Make XY Event Layer" tool to map them.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to convert firstly to decimal degree, than you can add the location in arcmap.
The formula it is simple divide the seconds by 60 and add to minutes than divide minutes by 60 and add to degree. Your current coordinates should be (7.58694444, 1.93500000), dont forget to use geographic coordinates as coordinate system.
No programming is needed just the excel to convert into decimal degree = DD+(MM+(SS/60))/60

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Add XY command is expecting two numeric fields, so this is not going to work.

If you know Python, you could write a script that converts DMS to DD.

If not, the easiest way is probably to load your data in Excel, calculate lat and long values in two additional columns, and load the Excel sheet in ArcMap using 'Display XY data' from the table's context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the data in Excel and calculate the decimal degrees using this formula (assuming the data is found in cell A1):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("°",A1)-1)+(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("′",A1)-1),2)/60)+(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,FIND("″",A1)-1),2)/3600)
```

The same formula will work on x and y coordinates and then you can import your excel points into ArcMap and Display XY data

Answer (score 0):

The [Convert Coordinate Notation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-coordinate-notation.htm)
geoprocessing tool supports one- or two-field DMS format lat long input. You may have to experiment with the exact input format; I mainly use it for other conversions so I can't say whether it understands the degree symbol. Just be careful to match your input format with the input format you choose. Not only does the tool convert, it can populate fields with the x and y in other formats, such as decimal degree.